# MySQL подзапрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Обнаружил интересную фишку в MySQL, хотел узнать поподробнее.

Есть запрос вида:

```
select t.id,
    (select sum(something) from table t1 where t1.id = t.id) as amt,
    amt * 10, /* тут будет ошибка */
    (select id from table t3 where t3.id = amt) as amt_t3 /* тут не будет ошибки */
from table t
```

Оказывается, MySQL позволяет использовать значение `amt` из подзапроса в другом подзапросе `amt_t3`, но не позволяет использовать как `amt * 10` (т.е. вне другого подзапроса). Почему?

Comment: Как минимум потому, что порядок вычисления полей не определён

Comment: @vp_arth и как это стыкуется что в подзапросе использовать можно?

Comment: А можно ли? Если да - особенности реализации) Уверен, что подзапрос вида `(SELECT amt * 10)` работать не будет)

Comment: в тему https://stackoverflow.com/a/18020948/1216425

Comment: @vp_arth зато `10*(select amt)` будет :)

Comment: @teran, прикольно, ага) А если вдруг перестанет работать, можно в дополнительный запрос завернуть)

Comment: @teran, ты заменил комментарий, таки не работает?

Comment: @vp_arth а я не проверял :) просто криво пост по ссылке прочитал, изменил, да :) интересно, если первом подзапросе использовать алиас третьего поля можно? :) видимо планировщик магию творит какую то для подазапросов, особо нигде не документированную

Comment: а если их зациклить, одно в другом использовать и наоборот :D

Comment: это кажется и в 5.7 версии работать не будет, вот https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549 занятный топик, там есть ответ разработчиков на эту тему. хотя в 5.7.11 мб и работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется, вы задаетесь вопросом, почему выполняется второй подзапрос, но не выполняется умножение. Хотя должно быть все наоборот.

То что умножение не может быть выполнено следует из того, что алиасы, объявленные в инструкции `SELECT` могут быть использованы в выражениях `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` и `HAVING`. Про то что алиас может быть использован в самом `select` повторно не сказано вообще нигде, такого нет в стандарте, и это не реализовано в расшрирениях mysql. Что собственно можно видеть и в описании синтаксиса инструкции `SELECT`  [в документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html).

> A `select_expr` can be given an alias using `AS alias_name`. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`,
>   `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.

Что касается использования алиасов в подзапросах, то для версии 5.7.9 был опубликован [следующий баг](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79549). Он касается как раз использования алиасов внешнего запрос в `where` условиях подзапроса. В данном топике приведен следующий комментарий разработчиков:

> *1. Why is it stopped working?*
>
> A. It stopped working because we were screening the MySQL extensions
>   to the SQL standard. And when examining some crashing bugs due to
>   corner cases that were using references to aliased expressions, it was
>   decided that this extension was poorly defined and could be handled by
>   other means. But the crashing bug was using a subquery in the `WHERE`
>   clause, not in the `SELECT` list.
>
> *2. Why standard SQL was changed? (or it did not previously been given to the standard?)*
>
> A: This construction has never been part of standard SQL, it was a
>   MySQL extension to the standard. **The standard has never allowed
>   references to aliases, except within the `ORDER BY` clause.**
>
> *3. Does exists an option of the configuration that query will working again OR how to find all such requests that doesn't working?*
>
> A. We have reconsidered how to handle this problem, and will try to
>   revert the decision on not supporting aliases in subqueries in SELECT
>   list. Thus, we are reopening the bug.
>
> Here is a longer background for the original decision:
>
> Contrary to references to aliases in subqueries in the `WHERE` clause
>   (and in `GROUP BY`, for that matter), there is no reason (except
>   standard compliance) that we should not allow references to aliases in
>   the `SELECT` list, since they should be available in the same phase of
>   query execution. But the support in 5.6 was quite arbitrary:
>
> Given this: `create table t1(a int, b int)`
>
> Alias in SELECT list is not valid:
>
> ```
> select a+b as c,c+1 from t1;  
> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '`c`' in 'field list'
> ```
>
> But within a subquery, reference to `c` is valid:
>
> ```
> select a+b as c,(select c+1) from t1;
> ```
>
> And subquery must be after definition of alias:
>
> ```
> select (select c+1),a+b as c from t1;
> ERROR 1247 (42S22):  Reference `c` not supported (forward reference in item list)
> ```
>
> So, it is easy to say that support for references to aliases in `SELECT`
>   list was rather ad-hoc. Nevertheless, we will try to reimplement the
>   old solution, but with no attempt at cleaning up the obvious holes in
>   the support for this feature. But referencing aliases in subqueries in
>   the `WHERE` clause will not be reimplemented.

Отсюда видно, что:

- использование алиасов в подзапросах это расширение Mysql (хотя толком про это в документации и не написано нигде, есть, правда, упоминания про `HAVING` в подзапросах).
- использование алиасов было запрещено в предложении `where` подзапросов из за некоторые ошибок в их при их использовании.
- использование алиаса должно быть после того, как алиас был определен
- ну и как альтернатива вашей исходной *ошибке*, предлагается `(select amt*10)` либо `10*(select amt)` оба эти варианты должны работать исправно.

---

Что касается этого бага и упоминаний алиасов в HAVING подзапроса то в документации:

> The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in
>   the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions. However,
>   MySQL supports an extension to this behavior, and permits HAVING to
>   refer to columns in the SELECT list and columns in outer subqueries as
>   well.

а также из changelog версии 5.7.11

> MySQL 5.7.8 prohibited references to select list columns of the outer
>   query from the HAVING clause of a correlated subquery in the inner
>   query because they are not permitted by standard SQL. However, because
>   this is a frequently used extension, it is once again permitted.

в общем не знаю как этот having соотносится с вообще использованием внешних алиасов в подзапросах, но стоит проверить, заработал весь функционал в последних версиях или нет. у меня проверить не на чем.

Comment: спасибо! тема интересная действительно